# How to get float text file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a textfile .txt with the following structure:

```
a-011bbbad022b7889c
a-0cf9f08ade83aed64
a-0408c0e6745bc2563
a-074b8709a7e4c9751
a-0d083d670fd0587a9
a-0670147fdd4dfec3a
a-075429f00fe0cf19a
a-0b734cd1f480a2f3c
a-0d1422812bc7344f1
a-092b72359be9b447b
```

What is the easiest way to get data into an array?

Comment: Have you done any effort to at least learn how to read the file within python?

Comment: `contents = open('file.txt').read().splitlines()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import struct
output_arr = []
with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        float_num = struct.unpack('!f', bytes.fromhex(line.split('a-')[1]))[0]
        output_arr.append(float_num)
```

Comment: I don't see where the question specified the data needed parsed

Comment: It was specifically asked how to get the text as float.

Comment: it's not clear how do you want to convert the values. Are they in hexadecimal? byte representation or whatever?

Comment: @Paolopast I'm not sure what's unclear about the conversion. `bytes.fromhex` is a built in type and only has one function.

Comment: There are better ways to remove the prefix then using `line.split('a-')`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you can do this in just one line:

```
result = open("test.txt").read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Open and read

---

A `.txt` file can be opened and read like this:

```
with open(r"C:\\Path\to\file.txt", 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
```

## Split

---

Then, you can get the lines like this:

```
content = content.splitlines()
```

Comment: You can use readlines directly from the file

Comment: Right, I saw the other's explaination so I tought that more than a line of code would have been more usefull to them to understand.